# Get array output using php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php loop through associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189879/php-loop-through-associative-arrays)

i have this piece of code which gets me as an output an array like this here:

http://penelope-ns.net/fb/fig.jpg

How can i save the [name] as a variable $name?

The code i use to generate is this:

```
  $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); ///// Add this line
```

Comment: Wrap your output in <pre> tags to make it more readable.

Comment: can you please give me an example? because i don't know how to do it..

Comment: View the page source on the script that is dumping that array out. You'll see the structure much more clearly, and it will become obvious how to access the name keys

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply... so i need to do something like var_dump($friendlikes) ?

Comment: @FeratDucellari Your image appears to be `var_dump()` output already.  I'm saying just view the page source in your browser rather than viewing the HTML output in your browser, and you'll see all the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see:

```
$fbid = 500591729;
$name = $array[$fbid] ['data'] [0] ['name'];
```

Or for all names:

```
foreach ($array as $fbid=>$value) {
    echo $value['data'][0]['name'];
}
```

Comment: Yes..Thanks this is what i need... but how can i output all the names? any loop?

Comment: Updated the answer, though you could probably have found that out yourself using my first answer, right?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, i appreciate your answer!