# php loop through associative arrays

Tags: php, associative-array

Editing this code here on Stackoverflow and I'm really near to get the result I need.

So I have this code posted down here:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
if(!empty($friends['data'])){
$size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
    foreach($friends['data'] as $data){
        $fbid = $data['id'];
        $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 
    }
```

The `$fbfriendlikes` outputs me an array like this one : http://penelope-ns.net/fb/fig.jpg

What do I need to do is save the names in a `$return` value, all names.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Could we get the output in text, rather than an image?  I've got a script that formats it.

Comment: To me, it's just neccessary to output the names.. if it's in text format it's okay!

Comment: I'd still like the output as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$dataArray = $fbfriendlikes[$data['id']]['data'];
$result = "";
foreach($dataArray as $item){
    $result .= " ".$item['name'];
}
```

Comment: so, if i do return result, it's suppose to give me the names?.. Thanks!

Comment: `$result` should be a numerically-indexed array that contains the names from `$fbfriendlikes`.

Comment: If this answer helped, don't forget that you can accept it.  You even get rep for accepting an answer!    http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Hey, i'm having this problem here:

syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']'

Comment: Hey, one question, i seem to have a little problem, all i get from this is an output which says Array

Comment: try `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

Comment: My issue is this, i need to print all the names you showd me how to, but i can do it only by returning a value, this is how the module works and i'm not that expert to modify it.. so, i don't know how to do that.. this way, you shown me, the output is just Array

Comment: Just the names, as one long string?

Comment: Fixed so that it outputs the names as one big string.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$result= array();
if(!empty($friends['data'])){
    $size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';

    foreach($friends['data'] as $key => $data){
        $fbid = $data['id'];
        $result[$key] = $data;
        $fbfriendlikes[$fbid] = $facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for the answer, i just need to output friends likes, the names of the pages.. does you code do this?

Comment: Sorry i misinterpreted the 'name' concept. Thought it refered to friends' names. This will give you an array with the name of the likes, yes.

Comment: Can you please do me this last favor? I need to store all names in a variable $result, because the module retrurn the $result! Can you please insert this one?

Comment: I believe this is it. Test it, because the image for the array you provided is quite hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the logic seems to be pure :)