# Loop through array to get value

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php loop through associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189879/php-loop-through-associative-arrays)

i have a variable which prints an array names $friends, the output of it is something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Penelope-ns-test",
      "category": "Community",
      "id": "187099821418102",
      "created_time": "2012-06-14T15:00:59+0000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fabric",
      "category": "Computers/technology",
      "id": "194407767268061",
      "created_time": "2012-06-07T07:24:03+0000"
    },
```

etc...

I need to do a loop in order to get something like this : if friends[id] == 1203438484 {

}

else...

```
foreach($friends['data'] as $data){
                $fbid = $data['id'];
                $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 
                $fbname = $data['name'];
                $path = $protocol . '://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=' . $size;
                $image = theme('image', array('path' => $path, 'alt' => $fbname));
                $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
                $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';
                foreach ($fbfriendlikes["data"] as $fbfriendlikes) {
    if ($fbfriendlikes["id"] == 184759054887922) {

                $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
                break;
                }
                }
            }
```

Can you help me with the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($friends["data"] as $friend) {
    if ($friend["id"] == 12345) {
        // Do something with $friend

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please see my updated code? i am inserting it like this and i see no output.. $friends has somehow the same structure as fbfriendlikes..

Comment: `foreach ($fbfriendlikes["data"] as $fbfriendlikes) {` -- you are using the same variable as your data source and your iteration variable.  Try `foreach ($fbfriendlikes["data"] as $fbfriendlike) {` and adjust the variable name in the block accordingly.

Comment: Can you please do me one favor, just based on my code substitute what i need to substitute, i know i'll do any error, i mean which variable should i adjust... i'm just beginning to learn php. sorry for being dumb

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array['data'] as $friend)
{
    if ($friend['id'] == 1203438484)
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh cdhowie just beat me to it! :)

Comment: Can you please see my updated code? i am inserting it like this and i see no output.. $friends has somehow the same structure as fbfriendlikes..