# php array, loop to get the exact value

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, foreach

I have this code right here, where the `$friends` variable is an array with an output like this:

```
{
  "id": "1149862205",
  "name": "name",
  "first_name": "first_name",
  "last_name": "last_name",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/username",
  "username": "username",
  "birthday": "07/12/1990",
  "hometown": {
    "id": "108618265828550",
    "name": "name"
  },
```

while `$fbfriendlikes` variable is generated by the id of `$friends` and has this structure :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Penelope-ns-test",
      "category": "Community",
      "id": "187099821418102",
      "created_time": "2012-06-14T15:00:59+0000"
    },
```

Now, I need to print all `$friends` ids which like a specific id in `$fbfriendlikes`
My code goes like this:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
if (!empty($friends['data'])) {
    $size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
    foreach ($friends['data'] as $data) {
        $fbid = $data['id'];
        $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 
        $fbname = $data['name'];
        $path = $protocol . '://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=' . $size;
        $image = theme('image', array('path' => $path, 'alt' => $fbname));

        if ($fbfriendlikes["id"] != 184759054887922) {
            $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
            $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';    
            $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know **I have to do a foreach loop in `$fbfriendslikes` but I can't seem to make it work**.
Can you please give me an advice?

Comment: try foreach($friends["data"] as $FData => $Value), $FData is the array key , and $Value is the value..

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, so understand this if i'm correct please. What i need is to extract the id from $friends, this id i use it to extract data from $fbfriendlikes. What i need is to print the information from $friends but the condition has to be based on $fbfriendslikes. And please can you be more specific in where to edit the code?.. thansk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop through array to get value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194910/loop-through-array-to-get-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check inside you loop to get the ones that don't like.

```
$return = '';
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
if (!empty($friends['data'])) {
    $size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
    foreach ($friends['data'] as $data) {
        $fbid = $data['id'];
        $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 
        $fbname = $data['name'];
        $path = $protocol . '://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=' . $size;
        $image = theme('image', array('path' => $path, 'alt' => $fbname));

        foreach($fbfriendlikes['data'] as $like) {
            $likes = false; // set var to check for like
            if($like['id'] == '184759054887922') { // check if they liked it
                $likes = true; // set var to true because they liked it
            }
            if (!$likes) { // test var to see if false (they did not like)
                // print this if they did NOT like it, otherwise do nothing
                $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
                $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';    
                $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
            }
        }// go on to next in loop

    }
    echo $return;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, so the way you posted it is supposed to be the right way? Thanks!

Comment: given the way you presented your data, and the questions, I believe so. Essentially if you want to find those that DON'T like something, create a variable that is defaulted to false, you want to loop through them all, and set that to true (I edited my code so look back at it) if they like it, set it TRUE, and check that var. If it is false )they didn't like it), print whatever, if they did, do nothing and continue loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$return = '';
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
if (!empty($friends['data'])) {
    $size = variable_get('facebook_graph_pic_size_nodes','square');
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
    foreach ($friends['data'] as $data) {
        $fbid = $data['id'];
        $fbfriendlikes[$fbid]=$facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/likes'); 
        $fbname = $data['name'];
        $path = $protocol . '://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=' . $size;
        $image = theme('image', array('path' => $path, 'alt' => $fbname));

        $likes = false;
        foreach($fbfriendlikes['data'] as $like) {
            if($like['id'] == '184759054887922') { // maybe $like->id will have to be used instead...
                $likes = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$likes) {
            $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
            $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';    
            $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
        }
    }
    echo $return;
}
```

Comment: Did a few modifications. Try it now.

Comment: You see, thanks for the answers but the problem is that it seems like the if condition won't affect the result!

Comment: What i'm trying to reach to do is: if you go here and do fconnet, the first button on right, http://penelope-ns.net/fb/ it's suppose to get first friends id, then based on the id's retrieved by $fbfriendlikes i get for each friend the pages they like, then i echo all the friends of the user who don't like a specific page id, which is generated by $fbfriendlikes[id] ...

Comment: Besides, isn't it supposed to be something like [data][0][id]?