# iterate an array the right way

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php loop through associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189879/php-loop-through-associative-arrays)
>   [php array, loop to get the exact value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202747/php-array-loop-to-get-the-exact-value)

I've been posting this problem a few times, just because i can't seem to solve it, this is the last time i post it, i made a few changes, i hope i can get through it or otherwise i'm quitting!

So the point is i have this code, i have this $friendlikesid which has a structure like this

```
data {
name;
category;
id
}
```

I need to loop through all the id's to find one in specific.
Now my code is this, but it isn't working properly, it's supposed to print the friends who don't like a specific id.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($fbfriendlikes);$i++)
 { 
     if ($fbfriendlikes[data][$i][id] == 191777737516178) 
     {
        $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
        $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';    
        $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Didn't you read deceze's comment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206356/php-array-get-value-and-then-loop-with-a-condition#comment14712199_11206356 Improving your question does not mean *reposting* it. **Edit** your original question!

Comment: did you read the content of the question?

Comment: Did you read the content of deceze's comment?

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will work otherwise

**echo $row['data']['id']** in if statement under foreach loop to see the value

```
foreach($fbfriendlikes as $row){
if ($row['data']['id'] == 191777737516178) {
 $return .= '<div class="fimage">'.$image.'</div>';
            $link = '<a href="'.$protocol . '://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$fbid.'" target="_blank">'.$fbname.'</a>';    
            $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>';
            break;
            }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks... It isn't outputting me anything..